# How to add new column on the basis existing columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have `dataframe` like this

```
   id1         id2          Entry_Date
0  5344265358   55111095504 2018-07-13 00:00:00
1  5344265358   55111095504 2018-07-13 00:00:00
2  5344265358   55111095501 2018-08-13 00:00:00
3  5344265358   55111095502 2018-07-14 00:00:00
4  5441440119   55111366675 2018-08-13 00:00:00
5  5441440119   55111366676 2018-08-20 00:00:00
6  5441440119   55111366677 2018-09-21 00:00:00
7  5441440119   55111366677 2018-09-21 00:00:00
```

I want to add a new column based on existing column

I want to groupby by `id1` and `id2` then sort on the basis of date and then asign date of next group to previous group but as you can see data has repetitions

```
     id1           id2          Entry_Date          Next_Date
0  5344265358   55111095504 2018-07-13 00:00:00 2018-07-14 00:00:00
1   5344265358  55111095504 2018-07-13 00:00:00 2018-07-14 00:00:00
2  5344265358   55111095501 2018-08-13 00:00:00 NAN
3  5344265358   55111095502 2018-07-14 00:00:00 2018-08-13 00:00:00 
4  5441440119   55111366675 2018-08-13 00:00:00 2018-08-20 00:00:00
5  5441440119   55111366676 2018-08-20 00:00:00 2018-09-21 00:00:00
6  5441440119   55111366677 2018-09-21 00:00:00 NAN
7  5441440119   55111366677 2018-09-21 00:00:00 NAN
```

Comment: Can you explian more `then asign date of next group to previous group` ?

Comment: after grouping i want to sort on basis of date then assign date of next group to previous group. i mean in new column date of next group should be copied to all rows of previous groups of 'id1' and 'id2'

Answer (score 1):

I think need:

```
df['Entry_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Entry_Date'])

df1 = (df.sort_values('Entry_Date')
         .drop_duplicates(['id1','id2'])
        .rename(columns={'Entry_Date':'Next_Date'}))
df1['Next_Date'] = df1['Next_Date'].shift(-1)
print (df1)
          id1          id2  Next_Date
0  5344265358  55111095504 2018-07-14
3  5344265358  55111095502 2018-08-13
2  5344265358  55111095501 2018-08-13
4  5441440119  55111366675 2018-08-20
5  5441440119  55111366676 2018-09-21
6  5441440119  55111366677        NaT

df = df.merge(df1, on=['id1','id2'], how='left')
print (df)
          id1          id2 Entry_Date  Next_Date
0  5344265358  55111095504 2018-07-13 2018-07-14
1  5344265358  55111095504 2018-07-13 2018-07-14
2  5344265358  55111095501 2018-08-13 2018-08-13
3  5344265358  55111095502 2018-07-14 2018-08-13
4  5441440119  55111366675 2018-08-13 2018-08-20
5  5441440119  55111366676 2018-08-20 2018-09-21
6  5441440119  55111366677 2018-09-21        NaT
7  5441440119  55111366677 2018-09-21        NaT
```

Comment: will it remove duplicates from original data because i don't want to remove duplicates

Comment: and what about sort on the basis of  Entry_date after grouping

Comment: @MuhammadWaleed - Not sure if understand, what is expcted output if change `55111095502` to `55111095501` ?